# Dynamically generate Grids based on image size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website and I have two grids that will be functioning as the same though one is slightly different to the other. Both are Logo holders for Companies and Organizations etc.

"Grid 1" is located on the home page as an "examples" series. This needs to be 6 random images from the list of images I have (in my img folder)

"Grid 2" is located on the "Associated Partners"* however this is just a list of all of the Logo's - These logo's will all be clickable and that takes the user to that Logo's website. Again this is just all images from my img folder

Grid 1 and Grid 2 has the following HTML as placeholder with little CSS applied:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/KoopaTheTurtle/pen/zYadqOW) has the code for this Post

```
<div class="grid">
    <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

As I am wanting the Random Images for Grid 1, I also have the following JS file

```
window.onload = function () {
let myPics = [];

function showPics() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".img").forEach(function (tag) {
        let index = getRandomIndex();
        tag.src = myPics[index];
        tag.addEventListener("click", getImageName);
        tag.dataset.index = index;
    });
}

function getRandomIndex() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * myPics.length);
}

function getImageName() {
    alert(myPics[this.dataset.index]);
}
showPics();
};
```

So the things that I am struggling with is:

Grid 1 needs to have 2 rows and 3 columns yet I am unsure how to go about this due to my `grid-template-columns` I have in my CSS and to also float center. If I change `grid-template-columns` to be anything thats not `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr))` it breaks. Also if I try any form of Alignment, nothing moves

Grid 1 also needs to implement the, possibly working, JavaScript code that I have. I am unsure if its working as I asked a friend about it and he chucked me that and said "possibly works for what you need" and then went on Holiday (lol)

Grid 2 needs to be dynamically generated based on the number of images in the folder - that way there isn't a million empty squares on the page. These Grids also need population with the images however they should be "static" so in order of how they show up in the Folder I guess.

If it helps, I am hosting this website via Firebase, so any other implementations such as Databases and such can be done - though will need to be setup and learnt. I was using AWS but it broke for some reason and now using Firebase

**name pending*

Comment: can you add image of required output and current output, so easily understand

Comment: please can you provide a snippet code ?

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI [https://i.imgur.com/jvm7Fe6.png](This) is what I want it to look like with Grid 1 being a random assortment of images from the list. Grid 2 is going to be kinda like an instagram/pintrest image feed style of logos. I do want to make Grid 2 'dynamic' in the sense it will only make enough squares for how many logos are in the Images Folder

Comment: [Grid 1 - current - img](https://i.imgur.com/lkB98I8.png) ||

[Grid 1 - Current (code)](https://codepen.io/KoopaTheTurtle/pen/LYrOVwa) ||

[Grid 2 - Current (img)](https://i.imgur.com/50ec3Sn.png) ||

[Grid 2 - Current (code)](https://codepen.io/KoopaTheTurtle/pen/qBKVOWv)

Comment: you just need grid structure with dynamic this can be with simple looping data or loop folder files.          use ajax or php like fetch query to fetch data , then simply loop data.